# How to make layout with 3 elements where 1 is resizable

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table, display

I want to make layout where should be three elements next to each other, where the middle one should be resizable and the third one should have dynamic width.

I have already made layout with, css display:table where the middle one is resizable. But I dont know if it is correct or if there can be some better way how to make this layout.

Here you can check what I achieve with display table
http://modnyblog.sk/displaytable/

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? For example, what determines the resizing for the middle element (e.g. browser width, content)?

Comment: Am not sure what you mean, but the middle element should has same width as the first one with opurtunity to resize him with mouse click

Comment: @Luxato - I'm able to resize the middle one, so I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: @Luxato: If the you can resize the middle one, does it getter bigger or smaller? If it gets bigger, either the first one or the last one has to get smaller (or both). Please explain how the first and last one are affected when the second one resizes.

Comment: @haakon319 my question is if the display:table is good for this layout

Comment: @samurai_jane The first one should have fixed width 300px except mobile devices, when it should has for example 50px, so first one it is not affected

second one has default fixed width, but you are able to expand it with mouse click, 
this second one affect third one -> third one width is reduced

Comment: I posted an answer. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question asks for help modifying the DOM with javascript/jquery. In your comments, you also mention responsive design but I suggest that you master one thing at a time and then post another question. Therefore, I am not responding with anything that takes into account your layout with different screen dimensions.

You need javascript or jquery to adjust the size of the second column with a click. I've also used javascript to make the height of all the columns the same but you could do this with flexbox, as well. Making the height of all the columns is necessary because the first and second ones have no content– hence, no height. Although you could specify a height in pixels, it's not a good idea– it will limit you as you write more code and makes designing responsively much more difficult.

I am not a fan of using `display: table` for what you have requested so I have used `display: inline-block`. In my fiddle, I have also used vanilla javascript. This is simply my preference– you could write it using jquery but I'm moving away from relying on jquery (even though you could achieve the same result with fewer lines of code by using it).

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ctpz9z6/3/).

Comment: So you would use display:inline-block with javascript rather then display:table without javascript, do you?

Comment: You can use `display: table` to get the layout you want but you'll still have to use javascript/jquery to change the widths of columns two and three. The javascript I used to make all the columns the same height is just my preference.